# FTP access to a file accessible only by root

Tags: linux, permissions, ftp, symbolic-link, ownership

When I try to do the following:

`ln -s /var/log/exim_rejectlog /home/user/logs/exim_rejectlog`

It creates the symlink and FTP access to the logs directory can see it, but because files in /var/log/* are root access, FTP access to that symlink follows that permission/ownership instead.

I am trying to figure out a way so that my support staff can get access to mail error logs without providing full root access.  Any suggestions would be welcome!

Comment: An alternative is to change how the errors are logged. For example if you can log to syslog you can use rsyslog to log data to a database which you can then query using a web frontend etc.  Also, there are whole log infrastructures for managing and handling logs - logstash springs to mind (but may be overkill).

Comment: Wxim can log to an arbitrary place ir syslog - https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-log_files.html

Comment: Also wanted to mention I did something slightly similar 8 years ago and blogged it. You.might find the process useful in solving your problem  (although I did it for postgres and to record delivery attempts).  - https://my.host.net.nz/2012/06/29/summarised-database-logging-using-postfix-and-postgresql/

Comment: @davidgo How do you change Exim's LOG_FILE_PATH through WHM? Can't find it any of the exim or tweak settings.

Comment: No idea, I wouldn't go there. OTOH, if you have WHM someone is paying $$$ for support - ask the company for support.

Answer (score 1):

chgrp that file to a group designed to let them view such files (e.g. `adm`), making them group-readable. Then add your support staff to `adm` group so they can read it. The symlink itself isn't neccesary.

As an aside, FTP is not a protocol I would recommend for new developments.

Comment: How would I do this without a symlink given cPanel only allows access to /home/*/ ? And what would you suggest over FTP?